# how to change the paddle width by changing the radio buttons?

Tags: javascript

Working on a PONG game, where I would like to change the size of the paddle from the player. In the html page there are 2 radio buttons, easy or difficult
when i click a radio button switching between easy or difficult. How to do that?

---

```
var paddlePlayerWidth = 50;

function handleClick(myRadio1) {
  paddlePlayerWidth = 40;
} else {
  paddlePlayerWidth = 100;
}
}

// Player size paddle
function Player() {
  this.paddle = new Paddle(canvas.width / 2 - 25, canvas.height - 20, paddlePlayerWidth, 10); // 50=100
}
// Update paddle
Player.prototype.render = function() {
  this.paddle.render();
};
// move players paddle left and right
Player.prototype.update = function() {
  this.paddle.move(0, 0);
  for (var key in keysDown) {
    var value = Number(key);
    if (value == 37) {
      this.paddle.move(-4, 0);
    } else if (value == 39) {
      this.paddle.move(4, 0);
    }
  }
  // move players paddle up and down
  for (var key in keysDown) {
    var value = Number(key);
    if (value == 38) {
      this.paddle.move(0, -4);
    } else if (value == 40) {
      this.paddle.move(0, 4);
    }
  }
};




  <script src="pong_base.js"></script>
  <script>
    pongStart("pongArena");
    pongStop()
  </script>
  <p id="p2"></p>


  <input type="radio" name="group1" onclick="myFunction();" value="Gemakkelijk">Gemakkelijk
  <input type="radio" name="group1" onclick="myFunction();" value="Moeilijk" checked>Moeilijk<br>
  <p id="demo"></p>

  <script>
    //var scoreComputer = "0";
    //var scorePlayer = "0";
    //var paddlePlayerWidth = 50;
    document.getElementById("p1").innerHTML =
      "Computer Score: "; // + scoreComputer;
    document.getElementById("p2").innerHTML =
      "Speler Score: "; // + scorePlayer;
  </script>



</body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 1):

You can try something like below. when the radio button is clicked, the value is passed to the myFunction and the paddleWidth variable will be updated with that value.

JS

```
var paddlePlayerWidth = 50;

function myFunction(value) {
  paddlePlayerWidth = value;
}
```

HTML

```
<input type="radio" name="group1" onclick="myFunction(40);" value="Gemakkelijk">Gemakkelijk
<input type="radio" name="group1" onclick="myFunction(100);" value="Moeilijk" checked>Moeilijk<br>
```